What theories are there on a collective consciousness outside of animal brains?
Consider we as humans are made up of independent cells, and the electric signals in our brain give us consciousness. Is it possible we humans, our planet, or our actions, contributes to a collective consciousness which has the ability to reason and think?
Are there theories which discuss this possibility?
What if we individuals are a merely a single cell inside the equivalent of a brain for this larger consciousness for example?

I forget the name of the thought experiment that considers each person in China/India/some sufficiently populous country taking a set of rules and a telephone and using the phone to send “signals” to other “neurons” to simulate a brain at full scale, and then asking if the resulting “brain” made up of billions of individual humans would be conscious. I think this is likely relevant though.

Single cells in the brain (neurons) lack structure to support anything like its neural network, so we are not analogous to them, and if we are supporting parts of a hive consciousness it is likely not analogous to ours. The idea of 'hive mind' formed by humans goes back at least to Husserl, see Is humanity as a whole a philosophical zombie?, but not of 'hive consciousness'. Traditional presentations of the Gaia hypothesis do not ascribe consciousness to Gaia either.

This question, for me, falls in the category of "wouldn't it be pretty to think so". It proposes no reason to believe it possible and no way to test it. I think it needs to be developed more before it is philosophy rather than fantasy.

As well as collective consciousness, you also have the collective unconscious https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious

Yogacara's alayered storehouse eighth consciousness and Husserlian intersubjective lived lifeworld horizon...

The Gaia Hypothesis (Lovelock & Margulis) is the concept that the entire planet Earth functions as a single giant organism in many ways. Although consciousness is not a standard part of the theory, it's a natural extension of the concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis
Hofstader's book Godel, Escher, Bach has an extended discussion of the concept of consciousness distributed across multiple separate organisms (i.e. a hive of bees, or an ant colony). I'm not sure if he drew that from more formal sources, or formulated it independently. I believe it's also discussed in his I am a Strange Loop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach

Sorry, missed it.


The starting point of your post is the fact that each human
individuum makes their decision on the basis of the interaction of
their bodily components.
You ask whether this paradigm of “the whole
and its parts” scales to a next layer.

A candidate for the next layer is a family and its members.
Here we have examples of collective thinking and deciding – but not
necessarily of collective consciousness.  With decreasing similarity
this paradigm scales to bigger social groups, e.g. with the
institution of popular votes or political elections.

The internet is a global memory for human culture. But currrently as
a passive store, without the capability of reasoning. This may
change with further development of artifical intelligence.
Possibly an example from science fiction is Stanisław Lem’s classical novel "Solaris"
with the mysterious ocean on a distant planet.



To say that the Internet is at all passive is interesting, at least. Trends, online movements, memes, etc. all spread entirely from the Internet; producing ideas and “independent” action might not be quite fulfilling of the idea of “consciousness”, but an LLM trained on the whole Internet would also be independent of the Internet itself.

@controlgroup Would you say that an LLM trained on the whole internet is capable of reasoning?

I would actually argue that an LLM - no matter what it’s trained on -is not capable of reasoning, because it is not designed to do anything of the sort. I was more making the point that “the Internet” and “an LLM trained on the whole Internet” would be two distinct entities and whatever AI you can produce, reasoning or no reasoning, would not necessarily be a complete representation of the Internet, conceptually.

@JoWehler Yes, LLMs can reason. They can apply Chain of Thought.  They have also shown Theory of Mind.

@controlgroup LLMs are not designed  to do certain things just as little as you are designed to type on a keyboard.  Yet, you can do this.  LLMs are not algorithms.

@Philomath An LLM, by definition, is an algorithm and cannot perform thought. It is just matching words to previous words. I know this as someone who has worked on LLM projects before. It can appear to show chain of thought/actual cogitation, but they do not actually retain knowledge and do not actually "know" or "perceive" anything. It is just a predictor model that happens to work on human language and is trained very well. Keep in mind: Google Search was not specifically designed to bring up this website given that prompt, but it does so anyway. That is not a special property.

There are such things as theorem provers and similar algorithms which, arguably, can perform the same process of logical reasoning that we humans train ourselves to do. But LLMs are not even remotely related to theorem provers.

@controlgroup The way in which an LLM is an algorithm is only in the way it is a simulation of a network on a Von Neumann machine. The network itself has nodes with weights that are esatblished with backpropagation in the course of training on large dataset. If you know anything about LLMs then you know that it is a black box because if we look at all the weights of all the nodes we have no idea what they mean. So in what way is that an algorithm? No if -then decision tree anywhere...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are studies about Mycelia forming larger electrical communication networks beyond their identifiable singular parts. While this can be verified by the conscious scientific observation of such structures — its identifiable parts and constituent components pointed and singled out by the observers — we can notice that the verifiable result, in itself, incurs in a very interesting and complex consequence: it re-establishes the question.
"Conscious being" and, further on, a "collective consciousness", are concepts that demand a very detailed definition and are plagued by insurmountable terminology discrepancies between fields of study. Theorizing, for example, that consciousness is the ability (or function) of auto-perception and the capability of autonomous action (i.e.: "self-motivation") in relation to other auto-perceived singular consciousnesses is a step that further complicates, as it re-instates, the proposition.
Note for @sneftel: The capability of self-organization, by fauna or flora, is not a new, nor an obscure, field of study: its relation to what we define as "consciousness" is the key aspect of how we can sort out and test theories about it. All of them are still speculative, though, as there is no way to properly test them.
In short, such theories are very difficult to prove by their very nature — but they abound: from 'mirror neurons' to meditation and psychoanalysis. The term is relatively new, known to be coined by Émile Durkheim, a sociologist, in the early 20th century.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't think anyone's surprised that biological substances are capable of self-organizing into complex distributed systems. The OP was asking about a sort of meta-consciousness, assembled from (yet not immediately accessible to) conscious beings. Are you saying that the "identifiable singular part" of a fungus is conscious?

In Hegel's theory, the World Spirit exists through iteration in individual consciousness, ie. it evolves and is (only) insofar as the individual consciousness is being and thinking and reflecting, ultimately (if it does reflect methodologically) coming to the insight of its own identity with the World Spirit.
I think this is quite close to what you are describing since every individual consciousness contributes to the World Geist (or Spirit) as part of it and one step in Hegel's reflective process is realising that the other is part of the same dialectical process as oneself.

I don't have a positive answer for you, and the page on Consciousness on SEP doesn't have one either. But there is good reasoning why it would be hard to have such a theory that would find any agreement amongst large strata of people. I don't believe anything much can be said about this until we know (or agree, for that matter) at the very least what consciousness actually is.
As per Wikipedia on Consciousness:

Consciousness, at its simplest, is awareness of internal and external existence.

Note that it does not say that consciousness is expressed, for example, when an entity reacts to outside influence, or if an entity actively influences other entities or the context in which it lives, or if an entity is in some sense aware of some fact or statement. It is about awareness of existence.
Of course we can find a great many examples of where entities or systems act in some intelligent manner (with intelligence itself being divisible into several aspects). For example, any animal, even single-cell-organisms, and even some plants directly react with or even proactively act on their surroundings. Communication, as a feature, is very widespread - not only with humans, but arguably, again, from the smallest cells, via mycelia, up to whole superorganisms like cities, countries and so on. Famously, we now have LLMs/GPTs which can arguably act just like a human, and arguably the Turing test has been finished.
All of this is fine and well, but consciousness whatever it is, is not that. We are not even close to having an agreed opinion about what it means to be "aware" of "existence". We have no agreement about whether dualism is true or not (i.e. of whether there is something within our brains that is doing the observing, separate from the brain). Most people would probably agree that single-cell organisms or small cell clusters are not aware, no matter how well they act and react.
Most people would agree that just because some text on a computer screen says that there is an aware program running within, this is not enough to be true (any child can write a program which claims that - and everybody who has even a passing understanding of how LLMs and GPTs today work, technically, would probably scoff at the idea). Many computer systems (and other technological or super-societal) systems have an internal representation of their outer world (i.e., an automated system that sets dynamic speed limits within an area obviously needs to be "aware", in a sense, about the current state of how much cars are on the streets and so on and forth, but nobody would imply that the system is "consciousness" of anything). A nation, i.e. a politcal system; or a system of companies acting within a market, obviously are in some sense "aware" of each other and their neighbours, but nobody in their right mind would say that a nation is "conscious" in the same sense a human or possibly animal is.
So while several other answers correctly point out that all kinds of non-human entities show aspects of being an actor; or having some sub-aspect of intelligence; or are forming super-organisms; or have meaningful connections to aspects like life and death - that all has little or nothing to do with awareness and hence consciousness.
